# Convert Unix timing PySpark 13 digits

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, unix-timestamp, dataformat

I've been trying to change the UNIX date (13 digits the one on the first column on the pic) to a readable date:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#TRY TO CHANGE THE DATA FORMAT
sd = df.withColumn('Date2', F.from_unixtime(F.col("Date") / 1000 ** 3, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
display(sd)
```

This is the result:

[image]

The first column is the UNIX Date to convert, and the result is the in the last column, I don't know why it comes out in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

```
F.from_unixtime(F.col("Date") / 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

You don't need the `**3` part (it raises the number to the power of 3). So you divide by 1000000000. This is why the "Date2" in your case is almost the begining of UNIX epoch.